# what is the right Schema microdata type to use for News Card?

Tags: microdata

we have news cards on our site as shown below .. what would be the right microdata itemtype for this ?i am inclined towards treating it as "NewsArticle" but technically it's not, it's just a news card.

could someone suggest if there is a better itemType available for this ? or any other correct way tot do it.
[image: news container]

Answer (score 0):

as it's multiple items, maybe try a list of links to articles/postings, you could add `image` and `description`:

```
<div>
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" itemscope>
        <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
            <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
            <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/peanut-butter-cookies.html" />
            <meta itemprop="description" content="description" />
        </div>
        <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope>
            <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
            <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/triple-chocolate-chunk.html" />
            <meta itemprop="description" content="description" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or maybe try a list with full articles/postings

to do that, you'd combine ItemList and NewsArticle, by putting each article as an element of ItemList:

```
<div>
    <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
        <div itemprop="item" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemscope>
            <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
            <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
                <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/profile/johndoe123" />
                <meta itemprop="name" content="John Doe" />
            </div>
            <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Jane Doe" />
                <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/profile/janedoe123" />
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00" />
            <meta itemprop="headline" content="Article headline" />
            <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00" />
            <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" itemscope>
        <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
            <div itemprop="item" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemscope>
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00" />
                <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
                <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
                    <meta itemprop="name" content="John Doe" />
                    <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/profile/johndoe123" />
                </div>
                <meta itemprop="headline" content="Article headline" />
                <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
                    <meta itemprop="name" content="Jane Doe" />
                    <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/profile/janedoe123" />
                </div>
                <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg" />
                <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg" />
                <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, not sure if there will be any benefit with either option in the Google's SERP, most likely not.

check the guides:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/carousel

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/article